# Prevent my module controller accesing without user login

Tags: controllers, login

How can i allow my controller to work only for logged in users? If non-loggedin user accesses my controller, he should be automatically redirected to login page and after successful login, he reaches my controller. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use predispatch function of your controller:

```
class Some_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    }

    // other actions

}
```

And try to replicate functions which you find them another standard Magento modules. For example `Mage_Sales_OrderController` uses this function which you asked above.

Comment: Workable, but I think an observer on controller_action_predispatch would be a cleaner way.

Comment: Why, I have never seen that another Magento standard/community modules used event/observer approach to do this functional. In this case event/observer is little long and difficult way.